# How to turn base64 encoded data back into an image without using UIImage in Swift?

Tags: image, kitura

I'm writing a `Swift Server` that accepts and saves a `base64 String` which has encoded a `UIImage` via `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` (so I can compress it). This string is then sent as JSON, where it is saved to a `Swift Cloudant` database. However, the server doesn't have access to `UIKit`, so I can't refer to a `UIImage` in it's code to decode it back into a picture. Is there a way to turn the String back into a picture without using `UIImage`?

Pure Swift would be the best option, but I don't know if it's actually possible. My server is a `Kitura` one, hosted on `IBM Bluemix`. Thank you!

(The goal is to show the picture on a webpage.)

Comment: If you're displaying the picture on a website, then your web framework should have some means of deserializing the image. How are you creating the other contents for the site?

Comment: I've been able to turn `Data` into an `Image` object using a combination of the [FileUtils](https://github.com/oarrabi/FileUtils.git) and [SwiftGD](https://github.com/twostraws/SwiftGD.git) packages. SwiftGD does depend on [Cgd](https://github.com/twostraws/Cgd.git), but its otherwise pure Swift. You can see an example implementation at [kitura-image-server](https://github.com/udacity/kitura-image-server) — look specifically at the main.swift file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it can help but as you need to show this image on a website I, in an application where I need to show a webview with a image,used this (in the .html file containing my webpage)

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,#IMAGE_STRING#">`

and when I run the application the "#IMAGE_STRING#" is replaced by the base64 string containing the image , the result is : my image is showing perfectly in the webpage